# How can I prove that a circle is the only compact connected 1-manifold?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, differential-topology

How can I prove that a circle is the only compact connected 1-manifold? It makes sense intuitively but I could not change my thoughts in precise sentences.

Comment: Are we talking about smooth manifolds or topological manifolds? (Of course it can be proven for both, but the proofs are not the same.)

Comment: First convince yourself that a compact $1$-manifold is a glued-together finite set of open intervals.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I'm talking about topologcial manifold.